# What Encoding Do I Perform On Media Before Sending It In A HTTP Response Body

Tags: http, http-headers, mime

I am currently developing a HTTP server.

When a client requests a PNG, my response headers are properly formatted and respond with Content-Type : image/png

**What steps and encoding processes do I have to perform on my .png file to send it as a byte[] in the http response body?**

Thanks!

Comment: The answer would really depend on the platform, what are you using?

Comment: im getting a feeling this is a dud question :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None, unless specified by the [`Transfer-Encoding`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.41) HTTP header.

It is all very [well-documented](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.3).

Answer (score 2):

None. Just be nice and send the "Content-length" as well.

Comment: Thanks,  the content-length is sent

Comment: I am a bit flumuxed as my responce is a simple on with the correct headers, followed by \r\n\r\n then the byte[] of the png file.  IE and Firefox don't like it ?:/

Comment: What language are you using? Can you post your code in the question?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, none, HOWEVER, for extra credit your server should check if the client accepts gzip encoding (look at the 'accept-encoding' header) when sending text or xml documents (images are compressed already) and send gzip with a content-encoding header.

Also accept, accept-charset and accept-language should be respected.

All are documented in [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) (HTTP 1.1)